# Is there a faster git status -uno?

Tags: git

`git status -uno` causes it not to show untracked files.

However it is too slow, and cannot be put into shell prompt on a large repo. There are multi-GB of untracked files, and a few select files (the ones I am working on) which I want to track with git.

I'd like to avoid the ~1s pause with `git status -uno` and I know this can be done if we can just get git to not worry about any of the files that have not been added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not completely certain yet, but I think my premise was wrong.

Basically the 1 second pause comes when using oh-my-zsh's git lib which tends to call stuff like `git rev-parse` and `git status --porcelain` automatically in shell functions which are used to fill in prompt fields.

I think that if I went through all of those calls and ensured that they would not do any parsing of untracked files, and also consolidate it so that the shell only really queries zsh once for all its info (rather than calling `git` several times to grab different sets of data0 I should be able to get it running much faster.

there's no time to do that now though, so I can't be sure yet.